# How to bind pushpins to bing map using mvvmlight?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, mvvm-light, bing-maps

I'm trying to bind my custom pushpin model to bing map control using MvvmLight toolkit. 
here is my code behind.

```
    public class CustomPin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}


public List<CustomPin> Pins = new List<CustomPin>();


 private void BindLocation(List<Branch> branches)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < branches.Count; i++)
        {
            CustomPin pin = new CustomPin();
            pin.Id = i;
            pin.Latitude = branches[i].Latitude;
            pin.Longitude = branches[i].Longitude;
            Pins.Add(pin);
        }
    }
```

And my XAML is :

```
       <bm:Map x:Name="Mymap"  ZoomLevel="1"  Credentials="xxxxx" Width="1366" Height="362">
        <bm:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapPins" ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}">
            <bm:Pushpin>
                <bm:MapLayer.Position>
                    <bm:Location Latitude="{Binding Path=Latitude}" Longitude="{Binding Path=Longitude}"></bm:Location>
                </bm:MapLayer.Position>
            </bm:Pushpin>
        </bm:MapItemsControl>
    </bm:Map>
```

I cant see my pushpins when i run this code.Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the values to the list **_Pins** but you are binding it wrongly as **Pins**. So set your ItemSource as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding _Pins}"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ops sorry, i wrote it wrong. I'm pasing Pins actually.

Comment: @KaanYurdakök Use breakpoints and check whether you can get Latitude and Longitude values. As per your code, you can get Pushpin only when you have proper latitude & longitude values.

Comment: i have all coordinates but i think i cant bind values. But when i tried to bind one coordinate i can get the result but not for multiple binding

Comment: It should work in your case. As you said, you can bind only one value right? Either Latitude or Longitude?